# Is there a way to perform a Redis GET command with the built-in Apache beam Redis I/O transform?

Tags: redis, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

My use case for Google Cloud Dataflow is to use Redis as a cache during the pipeline, since the transformation to occur depends on some cached data. This would mean performing Redis GET commands. The documentation for the official, built-in Redis I/O transform mentions supporting a few methods:

read - "provides a source which returns a bounded PCollection containing key/value pairs as KV"

readAll - "can be used to request Redis server using input PCollection elements as key pattern (as String)"

It looks like the readAll does not correspond to a GET command though because the input PCollection would be used to filter the result of scanning a whole Redis source, so this isn't what I'm looking for.

I was wondering if there is something I'm missing when looking at the built-in I/O transform that would enable my use case, or whether there are alternatives like open source 3rd party I/O transforms that support it. Or, is this something that is fundamentally incompatible with Apache Beam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RedisConnectionConfiguration](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/redis/RedisConnectionConfiguration.html). It will give you a serializable connection that you can use in your transforms.

Comment: This answer is good. GCP's blog post https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1 talks about data enrichment using an external service during the transform. If the client is thread safe, you'd declare it statically in your transform. Otherwise, you'd instantiate it in the `startBundle` lifecycle method. The blog post warns about issues like overloading the external service and causing pipeline backpressure if you do this, and that techniques like grouping by key and batching requests to the external service can help with this.